# Two-letter answer riddle

Tags: riddle

I have your photo, in which you never smiled,

I have been stained by your blood,

I have a magic number which defines who you are,

You carry me when going out every time,

Who am I*?  The answer is a two-letter word.

Comment: My edit left the asterisk since it featured in two of the answers, but it doesn't actually make any sense in context. It should just be removed.

Comment: Similarly, the first line is always true, but every one of the next three lines isn't accurate. Almost none are stained by blood in *any* way; the number is never 'magic' in any sense; and–while some actions such as driving or flying may compel one to bring it–many to most people won't need it or bother carrying it just to, e.g., go to the market. Astralbee, I, and most others can guess what you're playing at but you're missing a country-of-origin tag or sth if you want all your clues to be accurate.

Comment: @IIy hope u got why * is there ..?

Comment: Of course not. As above, it should be removed. Still, it's your question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are:

> ID

I have your photo ,in which you never smiled ,

> You are not permitted to smile in ID photos such as on your passport.

I have been stained by your blood ,

> Many IDs indicate blood type. Some IDs also now contain biometrics

I have a magic number which defines who you are ,

> ID cards also have a unique identifying number

You carry me when going out everytime

> You carry your ID with you.

Answer (score 4):

To add to @Astralbee's answer:

"Who am I* ? Two letter answer riddle"

> An asterisk is often used as a placeholder, so this line implies that the first letter is "I" and that there is only one other letter.

Comment: But that asterisk shouldn't've been there in the first place, since it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score -1):

You could also be

> An **iPhone**.

`I have your photo, in which you never smiled,`

> An iPhone may carry plenty of photos that do not all necessarily include you in them. Thus, if some photos do not include you, then you are not **smiling** in them either.

`I have been stained by your blood,`

> Most iPhones nowadays scan your fingerprint. Blood needs to be in your finger for you to move it, as energy is delivered via the bloodstream! If it was not for your blood, your fingerprint would not be able to **stain** your phone as you must press your fingertip on the scanner.

`I have a magic number which defines who you are,`

> This magic number is your secret **passcode** that nobody knows except you!

`You carry me when going out every time,`

> You *must* carry an iPhone with you every time in case of an emergency!

`Who am I*?`

> The asterisk ($\ast$) is on the letter $\verb|I|$ because that is the first letter of **iPhone**.

`Two-letter answer riddle.`

> Although *iPhone* is not two letters, it must have your **IP** address.

This is the closest alternative answer I could think of.

Comment: Apart from not being two letters, 'never smiling' is different from 'sometimes not smiling' and 'needing blood to be present' isn't the same thing as 'stained'.

Comment: @lly for the former, I understand. But for the latter, fingerprints do stain your phone when you press your finger onto the scanner. I edited to include that detail :)

Comment: Sure, but if your fingerprints are staining it due to *blood* you're doing something wrong.